# ContentResolver losing reference to ContentProvider (SQLite) after it is deleted and recreated

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-testing, android-contentresolver

I've been writing unit tests for SQLite database in my app and this weird issue has crept in. There are multiple test files in the test-package which run sequentially.

Initially, in one of the tests, the ContentResolver is used to query the database using `mContext.getContentResolver()` and it works the way it should.

Then, in another test, I delete the complete database by calling `mContext.deleteDatabase()` and recreate the database using a SQLiteOpenHelper object by calling `getWritableDatabase()` on it, which also works fine.

The problem starts when after all this, the ContentResolver is again used to operate on the database and the ContentResolver now does not correspond to the same database as before.

Any Query / Insert operation done using ContentResolver does not correspond to the same operations done directly on the database ( I do an insert directly on the database and I get a rowId back but when I query for that row using ContentResolver, I get back an empty cursor)

I'm not able to figure out what's going on in here.